# Accidentally deleted home folder when trying to delete uneraseable files. (How can I get a permission to re-delete recovered files?)

Tags: permissions, data-recovery, delete

I recovered some files using testdisk/photorec.
After the recovery, I tried to delete the folders I didn't need. The trash says it's empty but the space on the disk didn't free up. Neither restarting nor system cleaning with 'Stacer' helped, so I googled this code to try to delete it with:

```
$ sudo -rm ~/.Trash  
$ rm -rf *
```

`$ rm -rf *` resulted in:

```
rm: cannot remove 'expunged/536363428/recup_dir.1055/f251507336.gz': Permission denied
```

for all the files. How can get the permission needed to *really* delete it all again?

Comment: Have you try `sudo` ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Liso could you please sent me a link or specific thing to google about using sudo, so that i can learn how it could help in my situation? I'm not very technically savvy to put it mildly.

Comment: @Algnis I edited it and tried to describe everything more closely. Is it better? Do you have any suggestions how I can make it clearer?

Comment: @laketax yes it is fine now but you could even do more !!! You can make the output of a command in code fences by putting ``` on the beginning and ``` on the end !!! I was told to review this question as it is your first question , So as it is a first question , You have done good . You can find more information in askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Algnis thank you for your care and recommendations. I was struggling with the ``` at first, thought it looked like three period marks and then I wondered why those didn't do anything.

Comment: Ya I tried to edit your answer and found that

Comment: Please can you tell that the output you gave is of which command ?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be correct

Comment: Please post the output of `ls -l` in home directory

Comment: You want to give file permissions ? Try with `chmod -R 777 ~/.Trash` replace trash with the path you want

Comment: Run `sudo rm -rf *`

Comment: ok i've fucked up... I ran ``` ls -l ``` and then ``` sudo rm -rf *``` and it looks like ive just deleted everything on computer... so i guess i need to do recovery now again, right? ... @algnis

Comment: Well **language** , I told you to run sudo rm -rf * in place of rm -rf * !!!! Yes now you need to recover !!! By adding another user and deleting the before one , I will write an answer to describe it  , give me 5mins